# Get aggregate sum of json array in Postgres NOSQL json data

Tags: json, postgresql, nosql

How to get aggregate `SUM(amount)` from "`refunds`" array in postgres json select 
Following is my data schema and structure:

Table Name: `transactions`

Column name: `data`

```
{
  "id": "tran_6ac25129951962e99f28fa488993",
  "amount": 1200,
  "origin_amount": 3900,
  "status": "partial_refunded",
  "description": "Subscription#sub_a67d59efb2bcbf73485a ",
  "livemode": false,
  "refunds": [
    {
      "id": "refund_ee4192ffb6d2caa490a1",
      "amount": 1200,
      "status": "refunded",
      "created_at": 1426412340,
      "updated_at": 1426412340,
    },
    {
      "id": "refund_0e4a34e4ee7281d369df",
      "amount": 1500,
      "status": "refunded",
      "created_at": 1426412353,
      "updated_at": 1426412353,
    }
  ]
}
```

Out put should be: 1200+1500 = 2700

```
Output
|---------
|total
|---------
|2700
```

Please provide global solution and not with static data

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should work on 9.3+

```
WITH x AS( SELECT
'{
  "id": "tran_6ac25129951962e99f28fa488993",
  "amount": 1200,
  "origin_amount": 3900,
  "status": "partial_refunded",
  "description": "Subscription#sub_a67d59efb2bcbf73485a ",
  "livemode": false,
  "refunds": [
    {
      "id": "refund_ee4192ffb6d2caa490a1",
      "amount": 1200,
      "status": "refunded",
      "created_at": 1426412340,
      "updated_at": 1426412340
    },
    {
      "id": "refund_0e4a34e4ee7281d369df",
      "amount": 1500,
      "status": "refunded",
      "created_at": 1426412353,
      "updated_at": 1426412353
    }
  ]
}'::json as y),
refunds AS(
SELECT json_array_elements(y->'refunds') as j FROM x)
SELECT sum((j->>'amount')::int) FROM refunds;
```

Comment: Here json data is variable so can i use "data" means field name instead of fixed string.
I m new with postgres, can you provide exact query with column "data" and dynamic, not with static

Comment: `refunds` CTE selects from x.y, if you want to select from tbl1.data just do so `WITH refunds AS(
SELECT json_array_elements(data->'refunds') as j FROM tbl1) (...)`

Comment: I ran `WITH x AS( SELECT json_array_elements(data->'refunds') as y FROM transactions ),
refunds AS(
SELECT json_array_elements(y->'refunds') as j FROM x)
SELECT sum((j->>'amount')::int) FROM refunds;` and got error `ERROR:  cannot call json_array_elements on a scalar` Please let me know if i am wrong

Comment: @mukund It seems your data is not always like in the example. If you're on 9.4 try  `SELECT json_array_elements(y->'refunds') as j FROM x WHERE son_typeof(y->'refunds') = 'array`.

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH AllRefunds AS ( SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'refunds') AS refund FROM transactions)
SELECT SUM( CAST ( refund ->> 'amount' AS INTEGER )) FROM AllRefunds;
```

---

If you need to know how the query is built:

1.

```
WITH AllRefunds AS ( SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'refunds') FROM transactions)
SELECT * FROM AllRefunds;
```

This selects all elements as JSON objects (done via `->`) from the array `refunds` that were found in transactions table and stores it in a new table `AllRefunds`. This new table only consists of one unnamed column.

2.

```
WITH AllRefunds AS ( SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'refunds') AS refund FROM transactions)
SELECT * FROM AllRefunds;
```

Here the added (second) `AS` renames the currently unnamed column inside `AllRefunds` to `refund`

3.

```
WITH AllRefunds AS ( SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'refunds') AS refund FROM transactions)
SELECT SUM( CAST ( refund ->> 'amount' AS INTEGER )) FROM AllRefunds;
```

Our array entries are JSON objects. So we return the field `amount` as a simple string with `->>` that we then cast to Integers and `SUM` all entries up.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(coalesce(trrefunds.refunds->>'amount','0')::int) as total from(
select  jsonb_array_elements(refunds) as refunds
from  transactions) as trrefunds
```

Answer (score 0):

With postgresql 12+ you can use [sqlpath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) language. Suppose that we have a table named my_table and a field named my_json_value, here is a sample query:

```
WITH my_table AS (
  SELECT
  '{
    "id": "tran_6ac25129951962e99f28fa488993",
    "amount": 1200,
    "origin_amount": 3900,
    "status": "partial_refunded",
    "description": "Subscription#sub_a67d59efb2bcbf73485a ",
    "livemode": false,
    "refunds": [
    {
      "id": "refund_ee4192ffb6d2caa490a1",
      "amount": 1200,
      "status": "refunded",
      "created_at": 1426412340,
      "updated_at": 1426412340
    },
    {
      "id": "refund_0e4a34e4ee7281d369df",
      "amount": 1500,
      "status": "refunded",
      "created_at": 1426412353,
      "updated_at": 1426412353
    }
    ]
  }'::jsonb AS my_json_value
)
SELECT
    sum(amount::numeric) AS sum_of_amount
  FROM my_table t,
  jsonb_path_query (t.my_json_value, '$.refunds.amount') as amount
```

Since `jsonb_path_query` returns table (set of jsonb) we use it as table expression.