# Parse 4-deep nested json array in Postgres 9.4

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, nested

I need some help parsing json so I can perform analysis on it.  It's remote station measurement data that comes with location.

I've got to answer two simple questions and Ive got so far but it's giving me a brain block trying to figure some of the behaviour.

Nested arrays (four deep) is the main issue. I can't work out why lateral joins on jsonb_array_elements calls aren't doing the job.

I'm using postgres 9.4.4

Sample json is below as is the pg/sql I'm trying it with.

Here's the sample json. Anatomy/spec of the data and a pretty version can be found below:

> {
>    "SiteRep": {
>      "Wx": {
>        "Param": [
>          {
>            "name": "D",
>            "units": "compass",
>            "$": "Wind Direction"
>          },
>          {
>            "name": "H",
>            "units": "%",
>            "$": "Screen Relative Humidity"
>          }
>        ]
>      },
>      "DV": {
>        "dataDate": "2014-09-23T20:00:00Z",
>        "type": "O",
>        "Location": [
>          {
>            "i": "3002",
>            "lat": "60.749",
>            "lon": "-0.854",
>            "name": "BALTASOUND",
>            "country": "SCOTLAND",
>            "continent": "EUROPE",
>            "elevation": "15.0",
>            "Period": [
>              {
>                "type": "Day",
>                "value": "2014-09-22Z",
>                "Rep": [
>                  {
>                    "D": "SSW",
>                    "H": "88.5",
>                    "$": "1200"
>                  },
>                  {
>                    "D": "S",
>                    "H": "91.6",
>                    "$": "1260"
>                  },
>                  {
>                    "D": "SSW",
>                    "H": "92.8",
>                    "$": "1320"
>                  },
>                  {
>                    "D": "W",
>                    "H": "92.8",
>                    "$": "1380"
>                  }
>                ]
>              },
>              {
>                "type": "Day",
>                "value": "2014-09-23Z",
>                "Rep": [
>                  {
>                    "D": "W",
>                    "H": "88.5",
>                    "$": "0"
>                  },
>                  {
>                    "D": "W",
>                    "H": "86.7",
>                    "$": "60"
>                  },
>                  {
>                    "D": "W",
>                    "H": "86.2",
>                    "$": "120"
>                  },
>                  {
>                    "D": "WSW",
>                    "H": "87.9",
>                    "$": "180"
>                  }
>                ]
>              }
>            ]
>          },
>          {
>            "i": "3005",
>            "lat": "60.139",
>            "lon": "-1.183",
>            "name": "LERWICK (S. SCREEN)",
>            "country": "SCOTLAND",
>            "continent": "EUROPE",
>            "elevation": "82.0",
>            "Period": [
>              {
>                "type": "Day",
>                "value": "2014-09-22Z",
>                "Rep": [
>                  {
>                    "D": "SSW",
>                    "H": "95.3",
>                    "$": "1200"
>                  },
>                  {
>                    "D": "SSW",
>                    "H": "97.4",
>                    "$": "1260"
>                  },
>                  {
>                    "D": "SW",
>                    "H": "97.3",
>                    "$": "1320"
>                  },
>                  {
>                    "D": "W",
>                    "H": "94.1",
>                    "$": "1380"
>                  }
>                ]
>              },
>              {
>                "type": "Day",
>                "value": "2014-09-23Z",
>                "Rep": [
>                  {
>                    "D": "WNW",
>                    "H": "89.1",
>                    "$": "0"
>                  },
>                  {
>                    "D": "WNW",
>                    "H": "88.0",
>                    "$": "60"
>                  },
>                  {
>                    "D": "W",
>                    "H": "90.9",
>                    "$": "120"
>                  },
>                  {
>                    "D": "W",
>                    "H": "90.9",
>                    "$": "180"
>                  }
>                ]
>              }
>            ]
>          }
>        ]
>      }
>    }
>   }

Which I'm loading in with this code:

```
drop table if exists foo;
create table public.foo (data jsonb);

truncate foo;
copy foo from <example json as above>
DELIMITERS e'\x02';
```

First specific task is to count the number of "D" keys which have value "S".
Second task is to group these by different values of "$" key.

So I'm just trying to parse the json into pg tables with this:

```
select
"locations_entries"."date" as "location_date",
"locations_entries"."value" -> 'i' as "i",
"locations_entries"."value" -> 'lat' as "lat",
"locations_entries"."value" -> 'lon' as "lon",
-- "locations_entries"."value" -> 'Period' as "Period",
"locations_entries"."value" -> 'Period' -> 'value' as "p_value",
"locations_entries"."value" -> 'Period' -> 'type' as "type",
left("locations_entries"."value"::text,64) || '...'  as "value"
from
(
select "data" -> 'SiteRep' -> 'DV' -> 'dataDate' as "date",
"data" -> 'SiteRep' -> 'DV' -> 'type' as "type",
"location_entry"."value"
from foo,
lateral jsonb_array_elements(("data" -> 'SiteRep' -> 'DV' -> 'Location')::jsonb) location_entry --,
--lateral jsonb_array_elements("data" -> 'SiteRep' -> 'DV' -> 'Location' -> 'Period' ) period_entry
) "locations_entries"
order by "i"
```

Note the second lateral join is commented out. More on that in a second

The call above returns two rows:

```
    location_date      |   i    |   lat    |   lon    | p_value | type |                                value                                
------------------------+--------+----------+----------+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
"2014-09-23T20:00:00Z" | "3002" | "60.749" | "-0.854" |         |      | {"i": "3002", "lat": "60.749", "lon": "-0.854", "name": "BALTASO...
"2014-09-23T20:00:00Z" | "3005" | "60.139" | "-1.183" |         |      | {"i": "3005", "lat": "60.139", "lon": "-1.183", "name": "LERWICK...
```

Now if I uncomment the second lateral join it returns zero rows:

```
 location_date | i | lat | lon | value | type | value 
---------------+---+-----+-----+-------+------+-------
(0 rows)
```

Yet if I look at what the value of "data" -> 'SiteRep' -> 'DV' -> 'Location' -> 'Period' is to see what I'm calling jsonb_array_elements on it's:

```
   i    |                               Period                                
--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 "3002" | [{"Rep": [{"$": "1200", "D": "SSW", "H": "88.5"}, {"$": "1260", ...
 "3005" | [{"Rep": [{"$": "1200", "D": "SSW", "H": "95.3"}, {"$": "1260", ...
```

Which (I think) should be fine.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how I can parse the multiple nested arrays into tables?

I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827578/postgres-9-4-jsonb-array-as-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059477/get-aggregate-sum-of-json-array-in-postgres-nosql-json-data) but can't apply these solutions to my json as they don't go deep enough or I'm misunderstanding my json.

Comment: The anatomy of the json can be found at the bottom of the page [here](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/product/uk-hourly-site-specific-observations/detailed-documentation)