# PostgreSQL - Adding up json values

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

This is my json column in pgSQL and I need to add up all of the "sum" amounts using pgSQL.

So the query should return "50" using the data below.

```
'{
    "1": {
        "sum": 5,
    },
    "2": {
        "sum": 10,
    },
    "2728": {
        "sum": 30,
    },
    "2729": {
        "sum": 5,
    }
}'
```

I did find something like this ([Get aggregate sum of json array in Postgres NOSQL json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059477/get-aggregate-sum-of-json-array-in-postgres-nosql-json-data)) that kinda works if I had my values in array, but I dont, so this gives me an error.

```
WITH x AS( SELECT
'{
    "1": {
        "sum": 5,
    },
    "2": {
        "sum": 10,
    },
    "2728": {
        "sum": 30,
    },
    "2729": {
        "sum": 1410,
    }
}'::json as y),
sums AS(
SELECT json_array_elements(y->'2729') as j FROM x)
SELECT sum((j->>'sum')::int) FROM sums;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `JSON` value is nested objects, We can try to use `jsonb_each_text` function to get all nested object which is contain `sum` field before `SUM` by that.

```
WITH x AS( SELECT
'{
    "1": {
        "sum": 5
    },
    "2": {
        "sum": 10
    },
    "2728": {
        "sum": 30
    },
    "2729": {
        "sum": 5
    }
}'::jsonB as y)
SELECT SUM((v.value::jsonb->'sum')::INT)
FROM x
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(x.y) v
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c9f84c71b9cc219c0a4d5340a45a1e61)